# RabbitMQ: is it possible to cluster cross-version?

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to cluster Rabbits that have different versions? For example, is it possible to have a cluster consisting of:

- node 0: RabbitMQ 3.7.19
- node 1: RabbitMQ 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, this is possible though not recommended. Because different version could have different features or behaviors, combining them in a cluster could lead to unexpected behavior, compatibility issues or even data loss/corruption.